# Explanation of this passage (Borel Cantelli part 2)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I'm trying to understand a passage in the proof of Borel Cantelli Lemma part 2.

Be $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ a probability space and $(A_n)$ a sequence in $\mathcal{F}$ such that $(A_n)$ are pair independent. If $$\sum^{+\infty} P(A_n) = +\infty \qquad \quad \text{then} \qquad P(\text{lim sup}_n A_n) = 1$$

*Start of Proof*

Be
$S_n = \sum_{k}^n \mathbb{1}_{A_k}$; $\quad$ $S = \sum_{k}^{+\infty} \mathbb{1}_{A_k}$; $\quad$ $a_n = \int S_n \text{d}P = \sum^n P(A_n)$

From pair independence

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int (S_n - a_n)^2\ \text{d}P & = \sum_{i, k}^n \int \left(\mathbb{1}_{A_i}- P(A_i)\right)\left(\mathbb{1}_{A_k}- P(A_k)\right)\ \text{d}P
\\\\ 
& = \sum_{i}^n\int \left(\mathbf{1}_{A_i}-  P(A_i)\right)^2d P=\sum_{i}^n  P(A_i)-  P(A_i)^2.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

I cannot get why the very last identity is true / where it is obtained.

I know that

$$\left(\mathbf{1}_{A_i}-  P(A_i)\right)^2 = \mathbb{1}^2_{A_i} - 2\mathbb{1}_{A_i} P(A_i) + P^2(A_i)$$

But cannot go on with the integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $$\mathbb P(X)=\int \boldsymbol 1_X\,\mathrm d \mathbb P,$$
gives

\begin{align*}
\int(\boldsymbol 1_{A_i}-\mathbb P(A_i))^2\,\mathrm d \mathbb P&=\int \boldsymbol 1_{A_i}\,\mathrm d \mathbb P+\mathbb P(A_i)^2-2\mathbb P(A_i)\int \boldsymbol 1_{A_i}\,\mathrm d \mathbb P\\
&=\mathbb P(A_i)+\mathbb P(A_i)^2-2\mathbb P(A_i)^2\\
&=\mathbb P(A_i)-\mathbb P(A_i)^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: The part I have hard times with is $$\int P^2(A_i) dP$$

Comment: but $\mathbb P(A_i)$ is just a number, so $$\int \mathbb P(A_i)^2\,\mathrm d \mathbb P=\mathbb P(A_i)^2\int \,\mathrm d \mathbb P=\mathbb P(A_i)^2.$$

Comment: Well that was "obvious" and easy. Once I read it :D
Thank you again!!